# How to zoom to specific coordinate on openlayer map WMS?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

I tried to set map center by method setCenter, but still not working. Map is not moving. I tried to used transform from projection to map projection and without successful. Here is part of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Batam GIS</title>
    <!-- Import OL CSS, auto import does not work with our minified OL.js build -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://batamgis.jelastic.skali.net/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css">
    <!-- Basic CSS definitions -->
    <style type="text/css">
        /* General settings */
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }
        /* Toolbar styles */
        #toolbar {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
            display: none;
        }

        #toolbar ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #toolbar ul li {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 1em;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }

        #toolbar ul li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: smaller;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #toolbar ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #toolbar ul li * {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        /* The map and the location bar */
        #map {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            height: 448px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 300px;
        }

        #location {
            float: right;
        }

        #options {
            position: absolute;
            left: 13px;
            top: 7px;
            z-index: 3000;
        }

        /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
        table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 90%;
            padding: .2em .1em;
        }

        table.featureInfo th {
            padding: .2em .2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #eee;
        }

        table.featureInfo td {
            background: #fff;
        }

        table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
            background: #eee;
        }

        table.featureInfo caption {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: .2em .2em;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Import OpenLayers, reduced, wms read only version -->
    <script src="http://batamgis.jelastic.skali.net/geoserver/openlayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var untiled;
        var tiled;
        var pureCoverage = false;
        // pink tile avoidance
        OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 5;
        // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
        OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;

        function init(){
            // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
            // and default to jpeg format
            format = 'image/png';
            if(pureCoverage) {
                document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
                format = "image/jpeg";
            }

            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                103.88943658903702, 0.9680605034743621,
                104.15031077055329, 1.1995421846569343
            );
            var options = {
                controls: [],
                maxExtent: bounds,
                maxResolution: 0.0010190397715479,
                projection: "EPSG:4326",
                units: 'degrees'
            };
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

            // setup tiled layer
            tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Geoserver layers - Tiled", "http://batamgis.jelastic.skali.net/geoserver/BatamGIS/wms",
                {
                    STYLES: '',
                    LAYERS: 'BatamGIS',
                    format: format
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
                } 
            );

            // setup single tiled layer
            untiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Geoserver layers - Untiled", "http://batamgis.jelastic.skali.net/geoserver/BatamGIS/wms",
                {
                    STYLES: '',
                    LAYERS: 'BatamGIS',
                    format: format
                },
                {
                   singleTile: true, 
                   ratio: 1, 
                   isBaseLayer: true,
                   yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
                } 
            );

            map.addLayers([untiled, tiled]);

        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(104.020278, 1.068333).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator
      );

    var zoom = 13;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat));

    map.setCenter(lonlat, zoom);
  }



    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>WMS version:</a>
                <select id="wmsVersionSelector" onchange="setWMSVersion(value)">
                    <option value="1.1.1">1.1.1</option>
                    <option value="1.3.0">1.3.0</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Tiling:</a>
                <select id="tilingModeSelector" onchange="setTileMode(value)">
                    <option value="untiled">Single tile</option>
                    <option value="tiled">Tiled</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Transition effect:</a>
                <select id="transitionEffectSelector" onchange="setTransitionMode(value)">
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <option value="resize">Resize</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Antialias:</a>
                <select id="antialiasSelector" onchange="setAntialiasMode(value)">
                    <option value="full">Full</option>
                    <option value="text">Text only</option>
                    <option value="none">Disabled</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Format:</a>
                <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setImageFormat(value)">
                    <option value="image/png">PNG 24bit</option>
                    <option value="image/png8">PNG 8bit</option>
                    <option value="image/gif">GIF</option>
                    <option id="jpeg" value="image/jpeg">JPEG</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Styles:</a>
                <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setStyle(value)">
                    <option value="">Default</option>
                </select>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a>Filter:</a>
                <select id="filterType">
                    <option value="cql">CQL</option>
                    <option value="ogc">OGC</option>
                    <option value="fid">FeatureID</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" size="80" id="filter">
                <img id="updateFilterButton" src="http://batamgis.jelastic.skali.net/geoserver/openlayers/img/east-mini.png" onclick="updateFilter()" title="Apply filter">
                <img id="resetFilterButton" src="http://batamgis.jelastic.skali.net/openlayers/img/cancel.png" onclick="resetFilter()" title="Reset filter">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="olMap">
 <title>Geoserver GetFeatureInfo output</title>  <style type="text/css">
table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding:.2em .1em;
}
table.featureInfo th {
    padding:.2em .2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#eee;
}
table.featureInfo td{
    background:#fff;
}
table.featureInfo tr.odd td{
    background:#eee;
}
table.featureInfo caption{
    text-align:left;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:.2em .2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Openlayers 3 you need to use,

```
map.getView().setCenter(lonlat);
map.getView().setZoom(zoom);
```

Instead of,

```
map.setCenter(lonlat, zoom);
```